# Can I sell a proprietary software with an LGPL library bundled along with it, without making my source code public?

Tags: licensing, lgpl, proprietary-code

I am making a commercial application for my own company.

I want to use PySide2 in it which comes under the LGPL license. I will be using PySide2 without any modification to it for designing the GUI.

My question is that if I will be able to sell the software packed along with PySide2 without making my proprietary code public?

If not, what are my options?

Comment: The other obvious option (which you may or may not have considered) is to get a commercial Qt license. PySide2 is also developed by the Qt company, so it's possible they will sell you a commercial license for that as well if you need it.

Comment: Yeah, but the price of the Qt Commercial License is too high. $5000 as one user states. That's literally the salary of one year of one person in a third world country such as mine.

Comment: That is the consequence of your decision of choosing open source. Choosing open source is fine, but when you talk about "your proprietary code" it seems like you never even considered the requirements from your end in the case of GPL and LGPL. The expense of this is a business decision to be considered. If it is too expensive then you are obligated to use something else. Whining about the requirements of the LGPL does not help.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You've already got the answer that LGPL libraries can be used in commercial software.  So far, so good.  There's more to this than meets the eye, though.

The thing is, [PySide2](https://pypi.org/project/PySide2/) is for using the [Qt framework](https://www.qt.io/) with [Python](https://www.python.org/) programs.

Besides the LGPL license for PySide2, you'll have to make sure that you comply with the [Qt licensing terms.](https://www.qt.io/licensing/)

The [Qt licensing FAQ](https://www.qt.io/faq/) lays out your options:

- You can get a commercial license which allows you to do everything with Qt with no concerns about opensource.
- You can use only those parts of Qt that are under the LGPL and have no concerns about opensource.
- The third alternative is to go with the GPL license, which will require your product to meet the GPL2 or GPL3 terms.

There are some portions of Qt that are only available under the commercial license.  There are differences in the available modules between LGPL and GPL licensing.

You'll need to look at which Qt modules you really need, and see which license fits your needs.

Since you want to keep your proprietary code under a proprietary license, your only options for Qt are to use the LPGL version or buy a commercial license.

---

As I understand it, the commercial Qt license is expensive.  I just checked, and a 1 year subscription for a single developer is currently over $5000.

I use Qt in my personal projects, but they are all under the GPL so I can use the GPL licensing on Qt and not have to pay for a commercial license.

Comment: Good catch. I didn't look into what PySide2 does, so I didn't see the potential further dependency on GPL-licensed code.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau:  It's a subject I've had occasion to look into.  I use PyQt, but I read  about PySide when deciding how to use Qt in my own projects.  The commercial licensing came up when the company I work for was looking into frameworks for mobile applications - Qt has support for mobile (Android and Apple,) bit it's just too expensive for the projects we had in mind.

Comment: @JRE there is also a start-up licensing option if you qualify (less than $100k in revenue): https://www.qt.io/start-up-plan/

Comment: @DanM.:  Cool.  I never noticed that.  The company I work for wouldn't qualify as a start-up, but you never know when it might come in handy.

Comment: @JRE: Well this is a giant pain in the ass. I was using qt because it was easy to design a interface using Qt Designer and Tkinter was really painful to use.

Do I have any other options?

Comment: All I can suggest is that you check what parts of Qt are available under the LGPL.  If everything you need is there, then you could go with that.

Comment: As a complete alternative, you might look at [Kivy.](https://github.com/kivy)  It is completely under the LGPL.  I don't think there's a designer, but then you don't really need one for it.  I used Kivy to make a prototype, and it was easy enough to make the GUI in code - and I must say that I was not building a standard GUI at that time.  We were trying out a new concept at work, and the user interface was completely custom made.  Kivy has a lot of standard elements, but it also has a lot of addons.

Comment: @user5793353, to ease your mind, only the licenses of the components that end up in your product are relevant. It is entirely acceptable to use GPL licensed tools in your development process while creating closed-source/proprietary software.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau:  You can use (for example) a GPL licensed editor to write your code and have no problems with licensing.  If you use the Qt Designer to make your GUI, though, then you will have to deal with Qt licensing because Qt Designer puts links to Qt libraries in your code - it has to.

Comment: @JRE, that is exactly what I meant. You can use Qt Designer, but you have to check the license of the libraries that were added to your project.

Comment: Does Qt Designer put links to Qt libraries in the code?  The .ui file is XML, and when you want to use PySide2, you use pyside2-uic, which generates python which generates PySide2 stuff, but I thought this was from the PySide2 world: i.e., from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

Comment: It generates a ui file, which assumes that you import the needed classes in code.  The code generator that converts the .ui to Python of course includes the needed imports.  It's perhaps inaccurate to say that Designer puts links the libraries, but you can't use what Designer produces without the libraries - and that's where the licensing comes in.

Comment: Yeah, but the libraries can be PySide2, which are LGPL, which is what makes me think this might be OK (of course, IANAL...).  The whole thing gives me a headache.   Trying to get in touch with qt.io, who should be able to say how one would actually be compliant with the LGPL.   I've seen this question pop up time and time again.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you are using PyQt or PySide.  If you use something that requires a non-GPL or non-LGPL  part of Qt, then you'll have to deal with the Qt proprietary licensing.

Answer (score 23):

Yes, you can distribute your software without making the source code public and without giving recipients the right to make changes to your software.

The LGPL license explicitly allows such usages of libraries/packages released under that license.

When using an LGPL library/package like PySide2, your obligations are

- to allow and make it possible that users of your software replace the library/package that actually gets used when running the software
- for LGPLv2.1, to provide to users of your software the sources of the exact version of the LGPL library/package that you used, when they want to have them.

Comment: to make possible the first point, it looks like someone needs to write a opensource adapter so that application is decoupled from library/package. It is not always possible to just replace a DLL, also a compatible compiler should be mentioned.. So the adapter is shipped with a license compatibe with LGPL (but not LGPL). Since OP case is python I think there are no problems, but just think to C or C++

Comment: @UberFace, if you statically link an LGPL library in a language like C or C++, then you must at least provide the object files that were built from your code, so that your users have the possibility to relink them with a new library version. You will also need to provide the information that a software engineer would need to do the relinking. Using dynamic linking (DLL/.so) is then so much easier.

Comment: "Provide the possibility" -- no, you actually need to provide the source code, or a written offer. This is not a 'possibility' like (oh maybe possibly you can go download it over on blah blah blah web site), no, it means you actually have to provide the actual source code that you used. And probably you will have to spend a few pennies or a few minutes of your time to provide that; you cannot just push it on to someone else.

Comment: @Brandin, you are not required to ship the source code along with the provided binaries. A download link or written offer, so that the users can get the sources *when they are interested in getting them*. Anyway, I have rephrased that point.

Comment: When you do an 'import PySide2', is this dynamically or statically linked?   It seems like it is possible to use PySide2 in a commercial don't-release-the-source program, using the LGPL license, but what hoops would have to be gone through for this?  Any examples out there that show how it is done?   This is related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61566560/is-it-possible-to-fully-customize-a-ui-application-in-python-3-using-a-free-and

Comment: Importing pure python (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40492518/is-an-import-in-python-considered-to-be-dynamic-linking#40492802) is said to be static, but I don't know about import PySide2.

Comment: @asylumax, technically, there is no linker involved at all when running a python application. The important part for easy LGPL compliance is that the python interpreter decides at runtime which code to load when it encounters a import statement. That is equivalent to dynamic linking and is what makes it possible for end-users to provide a different package implementation.